# What is the impact of using frameworks with different SDK versions in the same project?

Tags: c#, ios, memory-management, xamarin.ios, ios10

I'm adding a [framework to an Xamarin project.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform-features/native-frameworks/)

Based [on the forums,](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32286/error-using-objective-sharpie-when-binding-zendesksdk) there is a dependency on the iOS SDK / Xcode installed.

If I use 1 framework in iOS SDK 9.0 and another based in iOS SDK 10.1, what is the overall effect on my application?

Are there memory, performance, or any other change that could occur with static or dynamic libraries ?

Answer (score 1):

Majorly there is no effect. But not for those **Classes and functions** which are deprecated in the 10.1 SDK. And if your application has linked with any *non-public APIs* of SDK i.e those APIs which are already upgraded to newer ones. Then your app will surely be rejected!

For example: Push notification, we have `UNUserNotificationCenter` in iOS 10 but we were using `UIUserNotificationType` and `UIUserNotificationSettings` to config notifications.